# Refresh markers on cluster manager

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

while the user navigates the map, the app will get new locations for he to see. But the map is not refreshing with the new markers.

After receiving a JSON with the places, this method put them on the map.

```
private void setMarkers(JSONObject response) {

    mClusterManager.clearItems();

    try {
        JSONArray venues = response.getJSONArray("venues");

        for (int i = 0; i < venues.length(); i++) {
            Venue venue = new Gson().fromJson(venues.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Venue.class);
            MarkerItem marker = new MarkerItem(venue.getLat(), venue.getLng(), venue, R.drawable.pin_quente);
            mClusterManager.addItem(marker);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The first request put them ok, but the second do nothing.

Answer (score 16):

Use:

mClusterManager.cluster();

After adding markers.

```
private void setMarkers(JSONObject response) {

    mClusterManager.clearItems();

    try {
        JSONArray venues = response.getJSONArray("venues");

        for (int i = 0; i < venues.length(); i++) {
            Venue venue = new Gson().fromJson(venues.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Venue.class);
            MarkerItem marker = new MarkerItem(venue.getLat(), venue.getLng(), venue, R.drawable.pin_quente);
            mClusterManager.addItem(marker);
        }

        mClusterManager.cluster(); 

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve my probleme with this solution.
It's less elegant but XYZ Communiccacion not work for me

```
private void setMarkers(JSONObject response) {

    mClusterManager.clearItems();
    mClusterManager.cluster(); //new code

    try {
        JSONArray venues = response.getJSONArray("venues");

        for (int i = 0; i < venues.length(); i++) {
            Venue venue = new Gson().fromJson(venues.getJSONObject(i).toString(), Venue.class);
            MarkerItem marker = new MarkerItem(venue.getLat(), venue.getLng(), venue, R.drawable.pin_quente);
            mClusterManager.addItem(marker);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //new code
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mClusterManager.cluster();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```